# What are the best Python packages/interfaces to sparse direct solvers?

Tags: python, linear-solver, sparse-matrix

Please list the Python package (petsc4py, etc...) and the sparse direct solvers it supports.  One (community-wiki) answer per package, please.

Comment: I was under the impression that "list" questions were considered bad form on StackExchange.

Comment: they are, in general, we're leaving this one up as an experiment, and to provoke discussion [here](http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/260/what-should-the-policy-be-on-the-phrase-one-book-solver-package-library-etc)

Comment: @JackPoulson: They are bad form. The question should probably be rephrased. Aron did a lot of triage on it that made it a *lot* better. As it is, we are leaving it up as an experiment to test the validity of the "one answer per package" phrasing of questions. There aren't that many potential answers (I think), so I don't think that the answer list will become unmanageably long. The main criticism of "list questions," vaguely defined, is that they're hard to maintain.

Answer (score 10):

All direct solvers supported by PETSc are available in Python under a common interface via [petsc4py](https://bitbucket.org/petsc/petsc4py/). Supported sparse direct solver packages include the PETSc native direct solvers, MUMPS, PasTiX, SuperLU, SuperLU_DIST, Umfpack, CHOLMOD, Spooles, LUSOL, MATLAB, and ESSL. See the `MATSOLVER*` man pages [here](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-dev/docs/manualpages/Mat/index.html).

Answer (score 8):

SciPy supports sparse linear algebra via `scipy.sparse.linalg` (see the [SciPy Documentation](http://scipy-lectures.github.com/advanced/scipy_sparse/solvers.html)). SciPy supports the sparse direct solver packages SuperLU and UMFPACK.

Answer (score 5):

[PySparse](http://pysparse.sourceforge.net/index.html) supports the sparse direct solver packages SuperLU and UMFPACK; see the [solver documentation here](http://pysparse.sourceforge.net/fact.html).

Answer (score 4):

All direct solvers supported by [Trilinos](http://trilinos.sandia.gov/) through [Amesos](http://trilinos.sandia.gov/packages/amesos/) are available in Python under a common interface via [PyTrilinos](http://trilinos.sandia.gov/packages/pytrilinos/). Supported sparse direct solver packages include UMFPACK, TAUCS, PARDISO, SuperLU, and MUMPS. See [this technical report](http://trilinos.sandia.gov/packages/pytrilinos/UsersGuide.pdf) discussing sparse linear algebra with PyTrilinos for some examples.